# Change JS array using Drop Down select

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to change which array is being used by selecting it from a drop down box. The script then randomizes items in the given array.

**The full code can be viewed here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lqkdp/**

**HTML:**

```
<select id="scale" name="scale" onchange="changeScale()">
<option value="array_Amaj">Amaj</option>
<option value="array_chromatic">Chromatic</option>
</select>

  <div id="scaleprint"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var array_chromatic = ['A', 'A%23', 'Bb', 'B', 'C', 'C%23', 'Db', 'D', 'D%23', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F%23', 'Gb', 'G', 'G%23', 'Ab'];

var array_Amaj = ['A', 'B', 'C%23', 'D', 'E', 'F%23', 'G%23'];

function changeScale()
{
  array_scale = document.getElementById("scale").value;
  document.getElementById("scaleprint").innerHTML = array_scale;
  array_chromatic = array_scale;
}
```

If the user selects 'Chromatic', the DIV called 'scaleprint' should update and the next part of the script should use that array to randomize and display the given note.

```
function renderKnuth()
        {
            array_chromatic.knuthShuffle();
            var audio = document.getElementById('sound');
      audio.src = 'http://lofiz.co.uk/gtr/dontfret/' + array_chromatic[0] + '.mp3';
      var str1 = array_chromatic[0]
      str2 = str1.replace("%23", '#');
            document.getElementById('knuth_data2').innerHTML = str2;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set array_chromatic to a string

```
array_chromatic = array_scale
```

this

```
array_chromatic.knuthShuffle()
```

is coming back undefined.

UPDATE

Change the values on your elements to numbers like this

```
<option value="0">Amaj</option>
<option value="1">Chromatic</option>
```

then change this

```
array_chromatic = array_scale;
```

to this

```
array_chromatic = my_arrays[array_scale];
```

and then add this

```
var my_arrays  = [array_Amaj, array_chromatic];
```

just below your array definitions.

Comment: How would I counteract that? Do I need to move the array vars down, after the changeScale function? Or am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Updated my answer to suggest a solution. I'm not sure that covers everything. Let me know if you need any other hints.

Comment: note that the order of the listing in my_arrays should match the `<option>` elements